# I have to disabled sunday from datapiker this is my code

Tags: javascript

I have to disabled sunday from datapiker   this is my code

```
<script language="javascript">
// alert('hello')
var today = new Date();
var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
$('#date_picker').attr('min',today);
$('#date_picker').datepicker({daysOfWeekDisabled: [0,6]
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  This looks nothing like python.   Please choose the correct tag for your question.  Also, what is your question?  What happens when you run your code?

Comment: through this code a have disabled previous date but also need to disable sunday from datepicker

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
$( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date){    
        return [(jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('DD', date)!='Sunday')];
                                  }
            });
  } );
```

```html
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>





 
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

Comment: This code is not Working because I have taken input Type = time